# How find this $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{1994}$ with this following system equation $3+2x_{i+1}=3|x_{i}-1|-|x_{i}|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find the all real numbers $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{1994}$ such 
$$3+2x_{i+1}=3|x_{i}-1|-|x_{i}|,i=1,2,3,\cdots,1994$$
where
$x_{1995}=x_{1}$

It is clear equivalent solve  following system equation real solution:
$$\begin{cases}
3+2x_{2}=3|x_{1}-1|-|x_{1}|\\
3+2x_{3}=3|x_{2}-1|-|x_{2}|\\
3+2x_{4}=3|x_{3}-1|-|x_{3}|\\
\cdots\\
3+2x_{1994}=3|x_{1993}-1|-|x_{1993}|\\
3+2x_{1}=3|x_{1994}-1|-|x_{1994}|
\end{cases}$$

I have some try,and can't solve it.

if we add this all equation,we have
$$3\cdot 1994+2\sum_{i=1}^{1994}x_{i}=3\sum_{i=1}^{1994}(|x_{i}-1|-|x_{i}|)$$
maybe consider this inequality
$$3+2x_{2}=|3x_{1}-3|-|x_{1}|\le |3x_{1}-3-x_{1}|=|2x_{1}-3|\le 2x_{1}+3?$$
I guess we can prove 
$$x_{1}=x_{2}=\cdots=x_{1994}?$$

Comment: What have you tried? What is the source? Didn't the source provide you an answer? Are you looking to challenge the folks here?

Comment: This problem is someone ask it by china QQ,maybe is 1995 exam problem.But he can't tell me this detail source

Comment: Why don't you include such info with every question? (you seem to be asking a lot of questions posed to you as challenges)

Comment: Yes,fisrt I like share problem and like try solve it,if you don't like this problem,you can't consider it.Thank you,bacause you ask what have you tried ?what is the source?Now I have add it.Then you say why include such info with every question,Now I have a bit get angry

Comment: Take it easy. You misunderstand. I said _why don't you include_ such info... which means, please do include the info for not just this question, but all other questions you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_{i+1} = f(x_i) = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} -x & \text{ if $x < 0$ }\\ -2x & \text{ if $0 \le x \le 1$ }\\ x - 3 & \text{ if $1 < x $}\end{array}\right.$
this dynamical system has three types of periodic orbit:

(a) an attracting $4$-periodic orbit $\{x, x-3, 3-x, -x\}$ for $1 \le x < 1.5$ and $1.5 < x \le 2.$

(b) an attracting $2$-periodic orbit $\{1.5, -1.5\}$

(c) a repelling $1$-periodic orbit $\{0\}.$

starting at any point, the orbit of the point eventually ends up in one of the three classes of the orbits above. therefore you only need to look for the starting points among the points in the periodic orbits listed above.

$1995 = 4*498 + 3,$ so none of the elements of the $4$-orbits can be $x_1.$ therefore the only candidates for $x_1$ such that $x_1 = x_{1995}$ are $x_1 = \pm 1.5, 0$; the laments of $1$ and $2$-periodic points.

Answer (score 1):

0 is stable.

Other numbers between -1 and 1 drift out to numbers with magnitude between 1 and 2.

Numbers with magnitude between 1 and 2 run a 4-length cycle above and below magnitude 1.5, except 1.5 and -1.5 which alternate.

Numbers with magnitude above 2 reduce to 2 or below.

The only three numbers which could qualify for $a_1 = a_{1995}$ are therefore {-1.5, 0, 1.5}.

Answer (score 0):

$x_{i+1}=\left\{\begin{array}{}-x_i,x_i<0\\x_i-3,x_i>1\\-2x_i,0<x_i<1\end{array}\right.$
How can that sequence of functions end up where it started?
If any $x_i<-2$, then $x_{i+1}>-2$ and the cycle will never return below $-2$.
If any $x_i>2$ then $x_j$ decrease until they are less than 2, and they cycle never returns above $2$.

Comment: Hello,I don't understand your methods,because if $x_{i}<-2$,then $x_{i+1}=-x_{i}>2$, why the cycle will never return below -2?can you explaine detail?

Comment: $x_{i+1}>2$ so $x_{i+2}=x_{i+1}-3>-1$.  If you start above $-2$ you never end below $-2$, so no number in the cycle is less than $-2$.

Comment: If you start between -2 and 2 you end between -2 and 2.  If you start above 2 you end between -2 and 2.  So all numbers in the cycle are between -2 and 2.